# How to give counter if more than one Notifications are there

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

I have implemented PushNotification Using C2dm. I am getting notification from c2dm also. My problem is I want to give a counter when I get more than one notifications, I mean like "You have a Notification(count)". How can I implement this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do to set the number value into the Notification object

```
Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.alarm,intent.getExtras().getString(KEY_TITLE),System.currentTimeMillis());
notifyDetails.number = 1; ////// here you can pass the counter value which will so you the number
```

here is the link

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#number

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

[Android Notification Bar Number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3042189/760489)

Comment: just a clarification as it took me a bit to find how to get it right. You need to change this, and then call back `NotificationManager.notify` with the same ID as the previous notification.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for [`Notification#number`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#number)?

Comment: I meant the public member named `number` in the `Notification` class, to which I also linked.

Answer (score 0):

```
NotificationManager notificationManager =(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notification.setNumber(1);
```

Comment: While this may be the answer it is better to include how and why the code helps to solve the problem stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

This creates the notificationManager class instance. Then you will have notification object with which you can do any adjustment. To set the number of the messages you have received, simply set this:

```
notification.setNumber(1);
```