# How to show Numbers as notification instead of image in android?

Tags: android, push-notification

I am new in android and i am trying to show notifications in notification bar. I have done showing Image icon in notification bar but i want to show the number notification as it comes in facebook notification.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiverActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    // Build notification
    // Actions are just fake
    Notification noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("New mail from " + "test@gmail.com")
    .setContentText("Subject")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
    .setNumber(4)    
    .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "Call", pIntent)
    .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "More", pIntent)
    .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "And more", pIntent).build();







    // Because the ID remains unchanged, the existing notification is     
    // updated.     



    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Hide the notification after its selected
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

Comment: Show us your code ... what you have done ...

Comment: i need a badge which shows number of notification

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7203541/how-to-give-counter-if-more-than-one-notifications-are-there see this answer

Comment: here is one good example you can see this and can implement some https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger